# Antlr4 grammar - Allow variable namess with spaces

Tags: grammar, antlr4

I am new to Antlr and I want to write a compiler for the custom programming language which has variable names with spaces. Following is the sample code:

```
SET Variable with a Long Name TO FALSE
SET Variable with Numbers 1 2 3 in the Name TO 3 JUN 1990
SET Variable with Symbols @ %^& TO "A very long text string"
```

Variable rules:
Can contain white spaces
Can contain special symbols

I want to write the compiler in javascript. Following is my grammar:

```
grammar Foo;

compilationUnit: stmt*;
stmt:
    assignStmt
    | invocationStmt
;
assignStmt: SET ID TO expr;
invocationStmt: name=ID ((expr COMMA)* expr)?;

expr: ID | INT | STRING;

COMMA: ',';
SAY: 'say';
SET: 'set';
TO: 'to';

INT: [0-9]+;
STRING: '"' (~('\n' | '"'))* '"';
ID: [a-zA-Z_] [ a-zA-Z0-9_]*;
WS: [ \n\t\r]+ -> skip;
```

I tried supplying input source code as:

```
"set variable one to 1".
```

But got the error "Undefined token identifier".

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So, what's the problem? A space is a character too, like any other character.

Comment: @PavelSmirnov I have updated the question with the error I got along with grammar and input source string. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
ID: [a-zA-Z_] [ a-zA-Z0-9_]*;
```

will match "set variable one to 1". Like most lexical analysers, ANTLR's scanners greedily match as much as they can. `set` doesn't get matched even though it has a specific pattern. (And even if you managed that, "variable one to 1" would match on the next token; the match doesn't stop just because `to` happens to appear.)

The best way to handle multi-word variable names is to treat them as multiple words. That is, recognise each word as a separate token, and recognise an identifier as a sequence of words. That has the consequence that `two words` and `two       words` end up being the same identifier, but IMHO, that's a feature, not a bug.